# Multiple ListViews with Custom Adapters in a Single Layout

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, tabnavigator

I created a Custom Tab Navigator and now I need to know how can I use multiple ListViews which will receive Custom Adapters.

When I needed to use a Custom Adapter I created a `ListView` with `id=android:list` and set the class to Extends ListActivity. But now I think I can't do that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To have multiple listViews on a single activity, don't need to extend ListActivity. Just add normal ListViews to the xml lauyout file and the reference them on the activity and set the adapters you want.

Example: xmlfile

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </ListView>

<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view2" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 </ListView>
```

On the activity:

```
setContentView(R.layout.xmlfile)...

ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view1);
ListView lv2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view2);

lv1.setAdaper(new CustomAdapter1());
lv2.setAdaper(new CustomAdapter2());
```

Comment: And can I set CustomAdapters without ListActivity?

Comment: Yes, of course, just create two different adapter classes and use them at will on your list views. Check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Nuno Gonçalves

A small mistake/optimisation in your XML-file:

In case of ListViews, it is better to define the `layout_height` and `layout_width` attributes both as `fill_parent` and scale them using the `layout_gravity` attributes. Setting the `layout_height` of a ListView to `wrap_content` is not optimal and can cause errors or performance problems.

But your solution will work in this case :)

Example:

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view1" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="1">
 </ListView>

<ListView android:id="@+id/list_view2" 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_gravity="1">
 </ListView>
```

Comment: I didn't pay attention to that as it was not the point. :) Anyway thanks for the correction.